# Zustand: property derived from other properties in the same state

Tags: reactjs, state-management, react-state-management, zustand

Consider the following zustand store:

```
const useStore = ((set) => ({
   property1: 2,
   property2: 3,
   property3: 6,
   //etc.
}))
```

Where property 3 is a multiple of both property1 and property2. Is it possible to set it up such that property3 automatically updates when either property1 or property2 updates in zustand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 1: You can use the hook inside the React component, which will have it's own state and update when property1 or property2 updates.

```js
function Component() {
    const property1 = useStore(state => state.property1);
    const property2 = useStore(state => state.property2);

    // Just for example, this multiples property 1 by property 2
    const property3 = property1 * property2;
}
```

Option 2: You can use [`zustand-store-addons`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zustand-store-addons), which adds computed properties

```js
import create from 'zustand-store-addons';

const useStore = create(
    (set) => ({
        property1: 2,
        property2: 3
    }),
    // Second object is for the addons
    {
        computed: {
            // Recomputes every time property1 or property2 changes.
            property3() {
                return this.property1 * property2;
            }
        }
    }
};

// The useStore state will look like
{
    property1: 2,
    property2: 3,
    property3: 6
}
```

Option 1 will be better if you're using the property only in one component, but if you'd like it to be a global property, option 2 will work better.

Comment: There's also these middleware libraries: https://github.com/chrisvander/zustand-computed https://github.com/cmlarsen/zustand-middleware-computed-state

Answer (score 1):

You can have derivative state straight from your selectors:

```
function Component() {
    const computedVal = useStore(s => s.property1 * s.property2);

    //...
}
```

Or, if your logic is too complex, you can extract it into an ordinary [custom hook](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks):

```
function useCustomValue() {
    const property1 = useStore(s => s.property1);
    const property2 = useStore(s => s.property2);
    return property1 * property2;
}

function Component() {
    const computedVal = useCustomValue();

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at zustand contributor [answer](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/issues/132#issuecomment-678555466)

```
const useAuth = create((set, get) => ({
    user: {username: undefined, authLevel: 0},
    signedIn: () => !!get().user.username
})}

// in components
function Foo() {
  const signedIn = useAuth(state => state.signedIn())

// vanilla non-reactive
const signedIn = useAuth.getState().singedIn()
// vanilla reactive
useAuth.subscribe(signedIn => console.log(signedIn), state => state.signedIn())
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that subscription for component update matters!
Your store computed getter:

```js
{
  getSelectedTemplate: () => {
    const { templates, selectedTemplateId } = get();
    return templates.find((t) => t.id === selectedTemplateId);
  },
}
```

Wrong subscription in component:

```js
const selectedTemplate = useStore(state => state.getSelectedTemplate)();
```

Correct subscription in component:

```js
const selectedTemplate = useStore(state => state.getSelectedTemplate());
```